# What is the story of this kamon?

Tags: japan, samurai, ancient-japan

I see that you have a lot of knowledge and I have been looking for information for several years. Do you know the story of this kamon? It is worn by my wife's family. It's Maruni ken Hanabishi; it is exposed like this in the house of the grandparents
[image: Framed kamon, formally displayed]

Answer (score 3):

In this [site](https://doyouknowjapan.com/symbols/), this kamon is named as Hiraoshiki Kenhanakaku. Kenhanakaku means "Sword flower horn". It is a variation of the [Hanabishi](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%94%90%E8%8A%B1%E7%B4%8B).

Generally I think you will find crests being used by different clans as they adopted symbols and crests from previous/other clans with which they were affiliated or to establish their legitimacy. For example a similar pattern is found in use by the [Goto clan or Uku clan](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Got%C5%8D_(Klan)).

These two pictures downloaded from [here](https://www.patternz.jp/japanese-family-crest-list-symbol/) have the Goto clan and Naito II using mon with a similar pattern:

[image]

[image]